# Angular unit test calling readonly BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, jasmin

I have a angular class implemented ControlValueAccessor interface too.

I need to have 100% coverage. Please help me to cover the remain.
Line 20, 35, 36 need to be cover. Tried my best seams I have missed somewhere.

Unit test code

```
import { ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { NgbPopoverModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { TestSharedModule } from 'src/app/test/test-shared.module';

import { CommentEditorComponent } from './comment-editor.component';

describe('CommentEditorComponent', () => {
  let component: CommentEditorComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CommentEditorComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        NgbPopoverModule,
        TestSharedModule,
      ],
      declarations: [CommentEditorComponent]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CommentEditorComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should call writeValue', fakeAsync(() => {
    const savedValue = spyOn(component.savedValue$, 'next');
    component.writeValue('A');
    expect(savedValue).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));

  it('should call registerOnChange', () => {
    let isCalledOnChange = false;
    const onChange = () => {
      isCalledOnChange = true;
    };
    component.registerOnChange(onChange);
    expect(isCalledOnChange).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('should call registerOnTouched', () => {
    let isOnTouched = false;
    const onChange = () => {
      isOnTouched = true;
    };
    component.registerOnTouched(onChange);
    expect(isOnTouched).toBeFalsy();
  });

  it('should call setDisabledState', () => {
    const disable = spyOn(component.ctrl, 'disable');
    component.setDisabledState(true);
    expect(disable).toHaveBeenCalled();
    component.setDisabledState(false);
  });

});
```

Here is the Component class

```
import { EventEmitter, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, Output } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ControlValueAccessor,
  FormControl,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { invoke } from 'lodash-es';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { distinctUntilChanged, map, skip } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comment-editor',
  templateUrl: './comment-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comment-editor.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CommentEditorComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class CommentEditorComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onTouchedFn: () => void;
  readonly savedValue$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

  readonly ctrl = new FormControl(null, {
    validators: Validators.required,
  });

  constructor() {
    this.savedValue$.pipe(skip(1)).subscribe((value) => {
      this.ctrl.setValue(value);
      this.setDisabledState(Boolean(value));
    });
  }

  writeValue(val: string): void {
    this.savedValue$.next(val);
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.savedValue$.pipe(skip(1), distinctUntilChanged()).subscribe(fn);
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouchedFn = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    invoke(this.ctrl, isDisabled ? 'disable' : 'enable');
  }
}
```

And here is the coverage result

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text and not as an image. Imagine someone willing to help but said person has to type all of the component down in order to be able to write a test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you spy on a method, you lose implementation details but gain access to when it was called, how it was called and how many times it was called. To get the best of both world, you have to add `.and.callThrough()`.

Try the following:

```
it('should call writeValue', fakeAsync(() => {
    // add .and.callThrough() here so next time savedValue$.next() is called,
    // the actual method is called
    const savedValue = spyOn(component.savedValue$, 'next').and.callThrough();
    component.writeValue('A');
    expect(savedValue).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
```

Comment: AliF50  any idea to cover line 20 ?

Comment: I am not sure. Maybe try painting/rendering `<app-comment-editor [(ngModel)]="value"></app-comment-editor>` in a component (`class TestComponent { value = 'abc' }` and render `TestComponent` in a unit test to see if that line gets covered. I am thinking the `ngModel` should cover that.